# HTML 5 Validator error with tooltip pop of thumbnail Websites

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

This is not validating in the w3c validator in HTML5 for some reason. Has anybody else ran into this error? Below is the code. It uses a Ajax or Jquery pop up to show a screenshot of a website so it's very tricky to change anything. Any suggestions?

```
<a href="http://www.careerrequirement.com/disc-jockey.htm" class="screenshot" rel="linkshots/dj.png" title="Be A DJ!">DJ</a>
```

Error is:

> Bad value linkshots/dj.png for attribute rel on element a:  Not an
>   absolute IRI. The string linkshots/dj.png is not a registered keyword
>   or absolute URL.

Answer (score 1):

Well it says it in the error: It's not a complete URL.

You can fix this either by changing it to a complete URL ( http://www.website.com/linkshots/dj.png ) or by using a HTML 5 data field.

Examples follow:

```
<a href="http://www.careerrequirement.com/disc-jockey.htm" class="screenshot" rel="http://www.website.com/linkshots/dj.png" title="Be A DJ!">DJ</a>
```

or

```
<a href="http://www.careerrequirement.com/disc-jockey.htm" class="screenshot" data-rel="linkshots/dj.png" title="Be A DJ!">DJ</a>
```

And then accessing it in jQuery in your AJAX pop-up via

```
$(this).attr('data-rel')
```

Further information on HTML 5 data attributes can be obtained at http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/ or at http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Comment: I appreciate that tip my friend, but I guess I'll just use the old phrase if it isn't broke don't fix it. Even if it doesn't validate in w3c it still shows the pop up using rel="linkshots/dj.png" I tried your suggestion with the data but didn't work for me. When I publish it i'll go back and put the entire web address in and revalidate it. Thank you brother.